# Why \$ \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_p} \$ is very high in GaAs compared to Si or Ge

Tags: semiconductors

Why Electron to hole mobility ratio is very high in GaAs compared to Si or Ge?
That is \$ \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_p} \$ (in GaAs) \$ =21.25 \$ whereas
\$ \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_p} \$ (in Si or Ge) \$ \in [2.1,2.6] \$ at Room Temperature

My Thoughts:
May be because GaAs is a compound semiconductor

Comment: Because it is???????? Or do you mean why is it different in different materials? Sounds more like a physics site question, as we're talking bandgaps, scattering centres, Fermi levels, nasty stuff I've not thought about since uni.

Comment: No i mean if Electron to hole mobility ratio of Ge or Si is in between \$ [2.1,2.6] \$ then why GaAs has too high ratio??There must be some reason...

Comment: Exactly, but it is more about physics than about electronics design.

Comment: A thought: Could have to do with the electron/hole masses. For Silicon: mp/mn=0.39/0.26=1.5, for GaAs: mp/mn=0.5/0.068=7.35.

Answer (score 2):

According to Chenming-Hu, *Modern Semiconductor Devices for Integrated Circuits*, Chapter 2:

> [...]Notice that GaAs has a much higher µn than Si (due to a smaller mn).
>   Thus, higher-speed transistors can be made with GaAs, which are
>   typically used in communications equipment.

Indeed, the normalized hole effective masses are comparable:

- Si: 0.39
- GaAs: 0.5

Whereas for the normalized electron masses:

- Si: 0.26
- GaAs: 0.068